# disable styles like equation in inline code blocks

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am using GitHub pages to write my blog, and an article about regex (regular expression) owns markdown code like this:

```markdown
---
layout: post
---

inline code blocks: pls replace `(\[(?:[^\]])(.)` by `$1~$2`
```

However, the resulting page is
[(compiling result of the above markdown)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Cnv.png)

I am new to Jekyll, so can anyone tells me what happens and how to avoid it? Here are my guesses:

- Jekyll thinks that there is an equation in `(\[(?:[^\]])(.)`.
- all is ok if the two inline code blocks were code blocks, but I think that it is too ugly.

My theme is

```
gem "minima", "~> 2.5"
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this, the same theme with your text results in inline code blocks. Do you have any other plugins installed?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I use `github-pages` and `mathjax`. This is my webpage [regex](https://qiancy98.github.io/programming/latex/2022/08/27/LaTeX%E6%AD%A3%E5%88%99%E8%A1%A8%E8%BE%BE%E5%BC%8F%E6%9B%BF%E6%8D%A2.html) and corresponding [source](https://github.com/qiancy98/qiancy98.github.io/blob/master/Programming/LaTeX/_posts/2022-08-27-LaTeX%E6%AD%A3%E5%88%99%E8%A1%A8%E8%BE%BE%E5%BC%8F%E6%9B%BF%E6%8D%A2.md).

Comment: It looks like the kramdown/MathJax parser too aggressively inserts math between `\[...\]`, even when they're part of an inline code block. Escaping twice, like with `\\[...\\]` prevents math, but the double backslash is still contained in the output. I have found [instructions](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#math-blocks) to escape `$...$` spans and `$$...$$` blocks; maybe there is a config setting that lets you exclude `\[...\]` as a math block delimiter?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for your direction. I solve the problem, as is posted as an answer.

Comment: Ah, great! It's currently almost impossible to diagnose that from the question alone. Maybe, if you want to make it more useful for others, add some more detail to the question about using MathJax, how it's configured, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Benjamin W. for his direction.
In [the document](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/options/preprocessors/tex2jax.html) there is an option `skipTags` that tells mathjax which code are needed to be skipped.
Add `code` to it solves the problem.